# Converting XML to HTML tab dynamically using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

i have an xml such as

```
<data key="xxx" value="xxxx">
<data key="xxx" value="xxxx">
...
<test> // a test object = a line in html table
    <data key="X1" value="1">// 1td
    <data key="X2" value="2">// 1td
    <data key="X3" value="3">// 1td
    <data key="X4" value="4">// 1td
</test>
<test>// a test object = a line in html table
    <data key="X1" value="7">// 1td 
    <data key="X2" value="8">// 1td
    <data key="X4" value="9">// 1td
</test>[....]
```

what i want to do is to represent the data fields within all the  elements (not the ones outside) in an html table, using the keys of the data as an HTML tab header where each row = a key.

My problem is that those keys are dynamic (i dont know them in advance). however,the keys will be same for all  elements but some keys can be null and not present in the xml such as in the example.

how would you proceed to have a result such as

```
<table>
    <tr> //my header tr data
        <td>x1</td>
        <td>x2</td>
        <td>x3</td>
        <td>x4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td></td> //nothing here because no value present
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what language or script are you using?

Comment: Can you add to xml all columns description?

Comment: well i believe it is xml and xslt no need of language right? i can use java.

Answer (score 0):

This is an classic muenchian grouping:

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:key name="kDataKey" match="test/data" use="@key" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="test" >
        <xsl:variable name="e" select="."/>
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="//test/data[count(. |  key('kDataKey', @key )[1] ) = 1]" >
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$e/data[@key = current()/@key]/@value"/>
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="//test/data[count(. |  key('kDataKey', @key )[1] ) = 1]" >
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@key"/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//test" />
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>X1</td>
    <td>X2</td>
    <td>X3</td>
    <td>X4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td/>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xml>
    <data key="xxx" value="xxxx"/>
    <data key="xxx" value="xxxx"/>
    ...
    <test>
        <data key="X1" value="1"/>
        <data key="X2" value="2"/>
        <data key="X3" value="3"/>
        <data key="X4" value="4"/>
    </test>
    <test>
        <data key="X1" value="7"/>
        <data key="X2" value="8"/>
        <data key="X4" value="9"/>
    </test>
</xml>
```

Comment: i might be wrong but it seems to me the  <xsl:apply-templates select="test" /> is never called

Comment: The `apply-templates select="test"` is "called" but it assume that the test node is a child of the first node in your xml. Your xml was not complete (not even well formed) so I have to do some assumption. I added my input. If your test nodes a on a different level you may use `apply-templates select="//test"`

Comment: thanks indeed it is working well. the only problem with the algorithm is that it will find the elements that are present and display the header of those elements first. then display the header of the elements not present (assuming there are no elements present in the first occurence of test)

Comment: To have the columns sorted, add a `xsl:sort` to the `for-each` loops e.g.: `<xsl:sort select="@key"/>`.